# How to setup CAS with LDAP authentication

Tags: active-directory, ldap, cas

I been trying to get CAS with LDAP working on tomcat all week. If I just move the cas.war file into the webapps of tomcat it runs but I need it to check LDAP for my user data.

I added dependencies like this :

```
<!-- Dependance support LDAP -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-server-support-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

And I added this :

```
 <property name="authenticationHandlers">
                        <list>
<bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler"
  p:filter="sAMAccountName=%u"
  p:searchBase="cn=Users,dc=mathieu,dc=local"
  p:contextSource-ref="contextSource"
  p:ignorePartialResultException="true" />
                        </list>
                </property>
        </bean>
```

but once I update the deployerconfigcontext.xml everything stops working
.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should have an awesome thousand line stack trace from Spring failing. Taking a guess, I expect somewhere there will be a subtle mention of not finding a "contextSource" bean:

```
  <bean id="contextSource"
    class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource"
    p:url="ldaps://XX" p:userDn="XX" p:password="XX">
    <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
      <map>
        <entry key="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple" />
      </map>
    </property>
  </bean>
```